# Old-releases hash broken. How I can ignore "Hash Sum mismatch"?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

I need to setup Ubuntu 7.10(gutsy) (not 17.10) repositories, so I've made local `apt.conf` and `source.list` files like this: (Host OS: Ubuntu 16.04)

`apt.conf`

```
Dir::Etc::main ".";
Dir::Etc::Parts "./apt.conf.d";
Dir::Etc::sourcelist "./sources.list";
Dir::Etc::sourceparts "./sources.list.d";
Dir::State "./apt-tmp";
Dir::State::status "./apt-tmp/status";
Dir::Cache "./apt-tmp";
Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order:: "gz";
Debug::Acquire::http true;
Debug::pkgAcquire::Auth true;
Debug::Hashs true;
Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth 0;
Acquire::http::No-Cache true;
Acquire::BrokenProxy true;
```

`sources.list`

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy main universe 
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy main 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy-security main universe 
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy-updates main universe 
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy-proposed main universe 
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy-backports main universe 
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy-security main 
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy-updates main 
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy-proposed main 
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy-backports main
```

however,  `apt-get -c apt.conf update` won't work due to the famous error, [`Hash Sum mismatch`](https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=apt-get+hash+sum+mismatch&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=jgOpWdKrKsWY8wXVup_QAQ).

I inspected http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/gutsy/Release file and I found lots of `.gz` file's SHA256 hash is same value with `baa89858c7e545390273530ba63c61b94c2e09d38c28b0a0311bfa7bde396181`. How could it possible?

Even though I don't use `apt.conf`'s `Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order` option, `apt-get update` won't work because of other files' Hash mismatch errors. My questions are:

1. How can I point out that `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com`'s hashsum is broken to its maintainer?
2. It is possible to ignore a `Hash Sum mismatch` error totally?

Edit: Obviously, `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` won't fix this issue.

Comment: @ali76 You didn't read my question. I've applied almost all suggestions in that question and it seems like this problem is a server-side issue.

Comment: Ok I remove duplicated , I didn't see `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` line in your question

Comment: As you say, those hashes are wrong. The files' sizes are different so they're not identical and it's *extremely* unlikely that SHA256 hashes would collide like this! I'm not sure this is off-topic--you're trying to enable Gutsy repositories in a Xenial system, not in a Gutsy system. But it's been getting some off-topic close votes as being about an end-of-life release. Can you tell us *why* you're trying to enable repositories for a very old release in a new one? (You could include this in an [edit].) Actually *installing* software from Gutsy repositories on Xenial is likely to break things.

Comment: @EliahKagan Sometimes I need to get very old release's packages (and source package), and it is not feasible to check each subfolder of http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool  . Thats why I setup old release's repository and being investigating  old-release.ubuntu.com's issue.